# I'm not receiving emails from my mail provider

Tags: email, dns, mx-record, google-cloud-dns

I've my domain hosted on Google Cloud DNS however my email provider is a 3rd party i.e iPage. After adding fields as recommended by iPage i.e adding '@' and '*' as host and mx.ipage.com as pointer but it still isn't working. My email starts from info@ but in the dns name, I'm actually adding '@' and '*'. Am I doing the right way?

Here is a screenshot of GC DNS:
https://i.ibb.co/71GfBK7/Capture.png

Here is a link to the ipage reqs for registering MX record:
https://www.ipage.com/help/article/dns-management-how-to-update-mx-records

Comment: DNS changes can take up to 24 hours to be refreshed everywhere, most ISP are faster and some might even update every hour.

Comment: I can wait for 24 hours but have I setup the right way?

Comment: No idea the ipage link linkes to a empty page where is no information on it, the information might be behide a login?

Comment: Just contact your hosting provider (IPage) for support you pay for that..

Comment: btw, iPage doesn't support 3rd party integration. The record have to be added in the Google cloud rather than iPage. My domain is hosted on Google cloud.

Comment: I think you are doing it correctly, however you should take into account the information from the following official documentation[1]. The port 25 is blocked by default in GCP. [1]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Comment: Thanks but I got it now. Actually, you don't have to add * or @ infront of the dns name. Just leave it blank and it worked instantly.

Comment: That's nice Abrar. Could you please put it as answer so it can be upvoted and help the community? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks but I got it now. Actually, you don't have to add * or @ infront of the dns name. Just leave it blank and it works instantly.